# Registering a new package in Julia fails

Tags: julia

I am trying to register a new Julia package, but `Pkg.publish()` fails. It says I need to call `Pkg.update()`. The latter tells me everything is already up-to-date.

What I get in my console:

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Updating RDF...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: No packages to install, update or remove.

julia> Pkg.register("RDF")
INFO: Registering RDF at git://github.com/joejimbo/RDF.jl.git
INFO: Committing METADATA for RDF

julia> Pkg.publish()
ERROR: METADATA is behind origin/metadata-v2 – run Pkg.update() before publishing
 in publish at pkg/entry.jl:259
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in cd at file.jl:22
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in publish at pkg.jl:53
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks,

Kim

Comment: Can you go into `~/.julia/v0.3/METADATA` and run `git pull`?

Comment: "Already up-to-date.". I use Julia 0.2.1 though. Should I update to the newest 0.3 release candidate?

Answer (score 5):

Solution: wipe Julia installation and delete `~/.julia`.

I re-installed Julia (0.3rc1 this time) and it worked as described in the documentation.

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" to list help topics
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.0-rc1+60 (2014-07-17 19:50 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit a327b47* (9 days old master)
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0

julia> Pkg.init()
INFO: Initializing package repository /Users/jbaran/.julia/v0.3
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl

julia> Pkg.clone("https://github.com/joejimbo/RDF.jl.git")
INFO: Cloning RDF from https://github.com/joejimbo/RDF.jl.git
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: Cloning cache of URIParser from git://github.com/Keno/URIParser.jl.git
INFO: Installing URIParser v0.0.2

julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Updating RDF...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: No packages to install, update or remove

julia> Pkg.register("RDF")
INFO: Registering RDF at git://github.com/joejimbo/RDF.jl.git
INFO: Committing METADATA for RDF

julia> Pkg.tag("RDF", :patch)
INFO: Tagging RDF v0.0.1
INFO: Committing METADATA for RDF

julia> Pkg.add("JSON")
INFO: Cloning cache of JSON from git://github.com/JuliaLang/JSON.jl.git
INFO: Installing JSON v0.3.7
INFO: Package database updated
INFO: METADATA is out-of-date — you may not have the latest version of JSON
INFO: Use `Pkg.update()` to get the latest versions of your packages

julia> Pkg.publish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of Julia 1.0 +, the workflow to register a Julia Package was removed from the package manager. Please see the [Readme for the Julia Registry for more info on registering a package](https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/Registrator.jl/blob/master/README.md).